# SMPP Server CloudHopper - Create Delivery Report

Tags: java, smpp

I have SMPP server, use CloudHoper.
When I get a message I should return a delivery report.
Please, tell me, how I can do it?

At this moment I return SubmitSmResp...

Answer (score 1):

Of course you still need to answer the SubmitSm PDU with a SubmitSmResp PDU as you do now.

A delivery report is a "special" DeliverSm PDU which is generated in your SMPP server and sent additionally to your client. See SMPP 3.4 Appendix B how it is formatted (https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp/blob/master/src/etc/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf). You also need to set esmClass of the DeliverSm PDU to 0x04 to indicate it's a delivery report.

If your client is using a transceiver bind, you can use the same session to send the DeliverSm PDU to, otherwise you need use the clients receiver session. If no active session is available you need to queue the DeliverSm PDU.

The main question is when to send the delivery report. First of all, you may send only a delivery report, if the client requested one, by setting the 4th bit of the SubmitSm esmClass.

Although, if your client is using a transceiver connection, don't send it directly in the firePduRequestReceived handler. The client may receive it before it receives the SubmitSmResp. Additionally this delivery report would not have more value than the SubmitSmResp itself.

So there are three cases when you may generate this delivery report and queue it until you have a proper session from your client to send it to:

1) When you receive some external event indicating that the former SubmitSm was actually processed (e.g. delivered) by it's destination.

2) When you are able to forward the SubmitSm to the next processing unit.

3) When you detect any error or the SubmtSm expired

Answer (score 0):

Create a DELIVER_SM for that message and send that to the client.